# Как с помощью словаря достать из списка часто встречающиеся объекты?

Tags: python

Дан список ip адресов. Как с помощью словаря достать из него 10 адресов, встречающихся чаще других?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать специальный класс `Counter`, который унаследован от dict. Он преобразует список в словарь где ключами являются элементы списка, а значениями - сколько раз ключ встречается в списке:

```
from collections import Counter

print zip(*Counter(ip_list).most_common(10))[0]
```